# How can i use Ajax request on multiple files?

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, ajax

I have a JavaScript file called `newsletter_init.js` and it makes an Ajax request.

I add this JS file to every .php on my project and the issue here.

For example I use `newsletter_init.js` in my `index.php` and a URL for the ajax request will be `res/ajax/request_newsletter.php`.

Ok, that's working but when I add the same JS file on another directory for example adding `newsletter_init.js` on a `index.php` but placed on blog folder the URL will be invalid as it will search for `../res/ajax/request_newsletter.php` instead of `res/ajax/request_newsletter.php`.

File structure about the scope:

```
index.php
blog > index.php
```

I have another way to do this:

1. Add content of newsletter_init.js on every file and change url but this is not a good way to approach this.
2. I have tried to use `__DIR___` in PHP but i don't understand how to use it in this situation.
3. I have tried `$(location).attr(pathname);` in jQuery but it return the fild name also for example localhost/homepage/index
4. I can't use a direct url as i will change from localhost to my site so, i need a dynamic way.

Comment: Just use a domain-relative URL, starting with a slash.

Comment: @CBroe Can you give an example for relative url? I mean how can i use relative url on multiple files?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just ensure your path is relative to the root directory.

```
/res/ajax/request_newsletter.php
```

Not:

```
res/ajax/request_newsletter.php
```

If you don't add the first slash, it will try to find that path starting in the directory where you are making the call (i.e. wherever your current PHP script is running).

Comment: Thank you so much, this made the whole project easier not just my problem